# Integrate the radial term of Laplace's eqn in cylindrical coords

Tags: integration

I'm reading a paper in plasma physics and I can't understand how they go from this:

$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta r}(r \frac{\delta \phi}{\delta r})=0
$$

to

$$
\phi = A+B\ln (r)
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

The way I was looking at it, you integrate both sides, the right side stays $0$, and then you divide by $r$, the right side stays $0$. And so you get that the derivative of $\phi$ is $0$, meaning it is a constant. I know I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the equation
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dr} \left( r \ \frac{d f}{dr} \right) = 0. 
\end{align}
Integrating both sides leads to
\begin{align}
\frac{d f}{dr} = \frac{a}{r},
\end{align}
where $a$ is a constant. Now integration again leads to
\begin{align}
f(r) = a \ln(r) + b
\end{align}
where $b$ is also a constant. If the condition is that $f << \infty$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$ then it is required that $a = 0$.